# Show that this function is cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, proof-explanation, cumulative-distribution-functions

I need to show that $F_{X}(x)=1-e^{-x \lambda} $ is a cumulative distribution function and I have:

i) $F_{X}(x)$ is monotone (that is $F_{X}(a)<F_{X}(b)$ for $a<b$
$F_{X}(a)<F_{X}(b) \Rightarrow  1-e^{-a \lambda}<1-e^{-b \lambda} \Rightarrow e^{-a \lambda}>e^{-b \lambda} \Rightarrow a \lambda<b \lambda \Rightarrow a<b$.

ii) $F_{X}(x)$ is continuos from the right (that is $\lim_{0<h\rightarrow 0}F_{X}(x+h)=F_{X}(x)$)
$\lim_{0<h\rightarrow 0}F_{X}(x+h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(1-e^{-(x+h)\lambda})=1-e^{-x\lambda}$.

iii) $\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty}F_{X}(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F_{X}(x)=1 $
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F_{X}(x)=\left ( 1-e^{-x\lambda} \right )=1$
But I cannot find the other limit and I don't know why.

Comment: What is the definition of $F_X(x)$ for $x < 0$?

Comment: You might wanna say that $\lambda>0$ otherwise your limit is wrong

Comment: Consider $F_X(0)$

Comment: Then note you have an exponential distribution supported on the non-negative reals

Answer (score 0):

This is only a CDF for a variable restricted to $[0,\infty)$.

In that case you'd define $F(x)=0 \;\;\forall x<0$

With this you have a valid CDF as your arguments show.